Can we bound the degree of a one dimensional smooth compact leaf of a holomorphic foliation in terms of its genus?
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over the complex numbers with a fixed ample line bundle $H$. Suppose that $\cal F$ is a foliation in curves over $X$ (which may be singular).
Can you find a constant $R=R(X,{\cal F},H,g)$ for which the following holds?:
Suppose that $C$ is a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ (perhaps strictly bigger than one) inside $X$ which is a leaf of the foliation $\cal F$ (not contained in the singularities of $\cal F$).
Then
$$H\cdot C\leq R$$
Observe that I am supposing that $C$ is a compact leaf of $\cal F$ which is also smooth.
Roughly speaking, I am asking if we can bound the degree of a smooth compact leaf in terms of the genus of it.
I found in the literature many results which bound the genus of $C$ in terms of the degree of it but nothing in the opposite direction.

What do you mean by the degree of $C$? If it is w.r.t. the embedding of $X$ in projective space, it suffices to change the embedding to get an arbitrarily high degree.

Thanks. I changed the question. I hope that now it is clearer.
